# Reference bash variable from a variable

Tags: bash, variable-substitution

How can I reference a variable in bash based on another variable? Let me setup the example:

```
package="foobar"

# the variable I wish to reference is $foobar_darwin_amd64
# thus trying:
echo "$package_darwin_amd64"
```

But this does not work.

Answer (score 9):

If you shell supports the `${!varname}` form of indirect references, you can do (as suggested by @Barmar):

```
$ foobar_darwin_amd64=pinto
$ package=foobar
$ varname="${package}_darwin_amd64"
$ echo ${!varname}
pinto
```

Otherwise, you can use `eval`:

```
$ foobar_darwin_amd64=pinto
$ package=foobar
$ eval echo \$${package}_darwin_amd64
pinto
```

That said, using `eval` has some risks associated with it, [see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17529221/5161900) for more discussion.

Comment: Why use `eval` when you can use an indirect reference?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution that worked for me:

```
VARNAME="${package}_darwin_amd64"
echo "${!VARNAME}"
```

Answer (score 2):

In bash v4 you can use a "[nameref](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameters)"

```
$ foobar_darwin_amd64=pinto
$ package=foobar
$ declare -n var=${package}_darwin_amd64
$ echo "$var"
pinto
```

The variable *name* you constructed can be obtained with the *indirect* variable expansion syntax:

```
$ echo "${!var}"
foobar_darwin_amd64
```